# How do I find the zeros of this function?

Tags: equation-solving

How do I find the zeros of:

```
1/Gamma[1 - I x]
```

The zeros should be $ -i\, n$ with $ n>0 $

I tried with `Solve[1/Gamma[1 - I x]==0,x]`, but I get the message:

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some
>   solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution
>   information.

So I tried with `Reduce[1/Gamma[1 - I x]==0,x]`, but I get `False` as a result

Comment: Use the identity `Gamma[z] Gamma[1 - z] == Pi/Sin[Pi z]` with `z=I x`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[x_] = 1/Gamma[1 - I x];

Plot[f[y*I], {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
FindRoot[f[y*I] == 0, {y, #}] & /@ Range[-5.25, -1.25]

(* {{y -> -5.}, {y -> -4.}, {y -> -3.}, {y -> -2.}, {y -> -1.}} *)

Assuming[{Element[n, Integers], n > 0},
 Limit[f[-m*I], m -> n]]

(* 0 *)
```

Comment: haven`t you started from the solution? I mean, in your reasoning, why you know already the argument of your plotted function? I am a bit puzzled, as I thought that the OP want to know the solution for $1/\Gamma(1-iz)=0$ by using MMA functions...

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas - Function is a given. `x` has to be pure imaginary to give a real argument to [`Gamma`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Gamma.html). Plot of the function suggests that the roots are near the negative integers. `FindRoot` verified that starting the search near a negative integer would converge to the integer. However, `Gamma` is undetermined ([`ComplexInfinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexInfinity.html)) at negative integers, so the roots only exist in the `Limit`. The last `Mathematica` statement verifies root for all negative integers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my proposal. The product of two gamma functions $\Gamma(z)$ and $\Gamma(w)$, with arguments satisfying the condition that $z+w$ is an integer, as in our case with $z=ix$ and $w=1-ix$, then:

$$\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1 - z) =\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$$

So:

```
Reduce[Gamma[I x] Sin[I \[Pi] x]/\[Pi] == 0, x]
```

$$c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\land \left(\left(c_1\leq -1\land \left(x=2 i c_1\lor x=2 i c_1+i\right)\right)\lor \left(i x\notin \mathbb{Z}\land \left(x=2 i c_1\lor x=\frac{2 i \pi  c_1+i \pi }{\pi }\right)\right)\right)$$

which includes your expected result.